# 10-char hash of an email

Tags: algorithm, email, hash, mailchimp

How reliable is it to use a 10-char hash to identify email addresses?

MailChimp has 10-character alphanumeric IDs for email addresses.
10 chars 4 bit each gives 40 bits, a bit over one trillion. Maybe for an enterprise sized like MailChimp this gives a reasonable headroom for a unique index space, and they have a single table with all possible emails, indexed with a 40-bit number.

I'd love to use same style of hashes or coded IDs to include in links. To decide whether to go for indexes or hashes, need to estimate a probability of two valid email addresses leading to the same 10-char hash.

Any hints to evaluating that for a custom hash function, other than raw testing?

Comment: Google for birthday paradox. For a 40bits hash the chance of collision reaches .5 if the number of items approaches 20 bits ( ~2E6) (that is: 0.5 chance of at least one collision for the whole set)

Comment: @wildpasser Thanks for the birthday paradox hint!

Comment: Change in any bit of key should change hash function's behavior. http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explicitly say what you mean by "reliable", but I presume you're trying to avoid collisions. As wildplasser says, for random identifiers it's all about the birthday paradox, and the chance of a collision in an identifier space with 2^n IDs reaches 50% when 2^(n/2) IDs are in use.

The Wikipedia page on [Birthday Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) has a great table illustrating probabilities for collisions under various parameters; for instance with 64 bits and a desired maximum collision probability of 1 in 1 million, you can have about 6 million identifiers.

Bear in mind that there are a lot more efficient ways to represent data in characters than hex; base64, for instance, gives you 3 bytes per 4 characters, meaning 10 characters gives you 60 bits, instead of 40 with hex.